# Electron: recibir valor y actualizarlo sin recargar la pagina

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, electron

Estoy tratando de editar un producto de un *Schema* y que actualice sus valores al momento de presionar el botón "editar". Cabe recalcar que uso Mongoose.

Así es como proceso y envío el `_id` y la `input.value`  desde `ipcRenderer` hacia `ipcMain`. Genero un `input` y este crea el valor a actualizar:

```js
let almacenProducto = [];
let idAEditar = "";
const inputEmergente = document.getElementById('emergente');

function editStock(id) {
  idAEditar = id;
  console.log(id);
  inputEmergente.innerHTML = `
    <div class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-end">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="number" id="inputQty" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad para modificar" >
      <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0"  id="getQty" value="search">Editar</button>
    </div>
  `;
  const getQty = document.querySelector('#getQty');

  getQty.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const inputQty = document.querySelector('#inputQty').value;
    ipcRenderer.send('editar-stock-total', {idAEditar, inputQty});
  });
}
```

Aquí esta el `ipcMain`

```js
ipcMain.on('editar-stock-total', async (e, arg) => {
  console.log(arg.inputQty)
  const stockEditado = await roductosExremos.findByIdAndUpdate(arg.idAEditar, {
    Stock: arg.inputQty
  }, {new: true});
  e.reply('stock-editado', JSON.stringify(stockEditado));
});
```

Y este `ipcRenderer` recibe y actualiza los campos sin tener que recargar la pagina actual:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('stock-editado', (e, args) => {
  const StockEditado = JSON.parse(args);
  almacenProducto = almacenProducto.map((t, i) => {
    if(t._id === StockEditado._id) {
      t.Stock = StockEditado.Stock;
    }
    inputEmergente.innerHTML = ``
    return t
  });
  productRender(almacenProducto);
  almacenProducto = [];
});
```

En realidad cuando edito el primer documento se actualiza sin inconvenientes, pero luego si quiero actualizar un segundo documento este recarga la página. Si alguien sabe que puedo hacer para solucionar esto le agradecería que me eche una mano. Gracias